# How do I properly insert into a Rust AVL Tree?

Tags: rust, avl-tree, ownership

I'm very new to rust and I'm trying to creating an AVL Tree. I used Rc because I want every node to be owned by nodes above it and RefCell to have it mutable internally.

I've started to build the "insert" method, but it isn't inserting a new node in the correct place, rather its replace the "root" node with the new node and I'm having trouble understanding why. I believe that this may be an ownership issue but I'm not sure.

```
use std::cell::RefCell;
use std::cmp::Ordering;
use std::rc::Rc;

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct BaseNode {
    pub key: u32,
    pub left: AvlTree,
    pub right: AvlTree,
}

pub type AvlNode = Rc<RefCell<BaseNode>>;
pub type AvlTree = Option<AvlNode>;

impl BaseNode {
    fn new(key: u32) -> Self {
        Self {
            key: key,
            left: None,
            right: None,
        }
    }
}

trait AvlNodeTrait {
    fn new_node(key: u32) -> Self;
}

impl AvlNodeTrait for AvlNode {
    fn new_node(key: u32) -> Self {
        Rc::new(RefCell::new(BaseNode::new(key)))
    }
}

pub trait AvlTreeTrait {
    fn new() -> Self;
    fn left(&self) -> Self;
    fn right(&self) -> Self;
    fn insert(&mut self, key: u32);
    fn dupe(&self) -> Self;
    fn set(&mut self, node: AvlNode);
}

impl AvlTreeTrait for AvlTree {
    fn new() -> Self {
        None
    }

    fn left(&self) -> Self {
        if let Some(node) = self {
            return node.borrow().right.dupe();
        }

        panic!("Trying to get Left of None!")
    }

    fn right(&self) -> Self {
        if let Some(node) = self {
            return node.borrow().right.dupe();
        }

        panic!("Trying to get right of None!")
    }

    fn dupe(&self) -> Self {
        match self {
            Some(node) => Some(Rc::clone(&node)),
            None => None,
        }
    }

    fn set(&mut self, node: AvlNode) {
        *self = Some(Rc::clone(&node));
    }

    fn insert(&mut self, key: u32) {
        let node = AvlNode::new_node(key);

        let mut curr_tree = self;
        let mut curr_key = 0;

        while !curr_tree.is_none() {
            if let Some(node) = &curr_tree {
                curr_key = node.borrow().key;

                if key > curr_key {
                    *curr_tree = curr_tree.left()
                } else if key < curr_key {
                    *curr_tree = curr_tree.right()
                } else {
                    return;
                }
            }
        }

        *curr_tree = Some(Rc::clone(&node));
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut tree = AvlTree::new();
    println!("{:?}", tree); // None
    tree.insert(5);         
    println!("{:?}", tree); // Some(RefCell { value: BaseNode { key: 5, left: None, right: None } })
    tree.insert(56);        
    println!("{:?}", tree); // Some(RefCell { value: BaseNode { key: 2, left: None, right: None } })
}
```

Comment: Imagine running through the code once. You have (`self: &mut ...`), and you have curr_tree = self. Do you know what the result is when you run `*curr_tree = curr_tree.left()`?

Comment: Have you read [Learning Rust with too many linked lists](https://rust-unofficial.github.io/too-many-lists/)?

Answer (score 0):

I would say the use of RefCell is quite unnecessary and potentially unsafe in this context. RefCell hands over the ownership/borrow checking to the runtime instead of doing them during compile time. This can lead to your program to panic in case it violates any of the borrowing rules.

I would prefer a "recursive" type looking something like this:

```
struct AVLTree<T> {
    val: T,
    left: Option<Box<AVLTree<T>>>,
    right: Option<Box<AVLTree<T>>>
}
```

This will of course introduce some overhead due to memory allocation.

Comment: Careful when using "unsafe" when talking about Rust, it has very specific meaning. `RefCell` are NOT unsafe to use, as you note they detect borrowing issues dynamically -- that's a feature -- and therefore delay diagnosis of issue (if any), nothing unsafe in that.

Comment: Please excuse the bad wording of my answer. I should have gone with something else since I didn't mean 'unsafe' in the rust way. What I meant to say was rather that for me RefCell is sort of a last resort if other approaches don't work out. Since it's easy to miss cases where it fails and then have the whole program crash on you.

Comment: No problem, and I do share your concerns and the idea of using as a last resort, I would just "fix" the answer to make sure not to mislead future readers.